# can not find setting for automatically generated email from analytics-noreply@google.com

Tags: google-analytics

I have Google analytics set up for about 20 different accounts/websites.  There is an email that I get from one of the sites that I can not find a setting for.  It is an autogenerated email that comes from analytics-noreply@google.com

It looks like this:

[image]

I can not find the place where I can enable this.  I have looked under the account/property/and view settings.  I am using the new universal analytics for every account.

I like this email and would like to get it for all my accounts and maybe even change the time period (if that's possible).

I tried googling[sic] the subject line but all I get are links to the Google+ page for google analytics, but no actual information.

**QUESTION:** Does anyone know where the settings are for getting this email?   Or is there a minimum visits number that has to be hit for this email to be generated?

Comment: In the future, I would ask this under Stack Overflow > [Webmaster](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), as it doesn't directly pertain to programming.

Comment: you right - will do in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've had this email come through for a few of our clients, too. I am thinking it's has to do with the Data Sharing Setting (Account > Account Settings) for Account Specialists. I believe it defaults to the default profile (view) that you initially setup for your account.

Just my two-cents though...

[image]

Comment: THanks, I have this enabled for all of the accounts, but there is only one account getting the email, but it is the account with the most visitors, so that is why I am wondering if there is a minimum visitor cut-off.

Comment: Could be... There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to what accounts they send to either.